# tinymce.PluginManager.add no longer working in wordpress 4.7.2

Tags: wordpress, plugins, tinymce

Here is the example of the code

```js
(function()
{
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'custom_class', function( editor, url )
    {

        // Add Button to Visual Editor Toolbar 
        editor.addButton('custom_class', {
            type: 'menubutton',
            text: 'Text Layout',
            icon: false,
            menu: [{
                        text: 'Testimonial',
                        onclick:    function()
                                    {
                                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
                                        editor.insertContent('<strong>Menu item 1 here!</strong>&nbsp;');
                                    }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Large Header Line',
                        onclick:    function()
                                    {
                                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
                                        editor.insertContent('<h4>Header</h4><em>Menu item 2 here!</em>&nbsp;');
                                      }
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Normal',
                        onclick:    function()
                                    {
                                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
                                        editor.insertContent('Menu item 3 here!&nbsp;');
                                    }
                    }]
            //image: url + '/icon.png',
        });

    });
    
    
   
})();
```

After Wordpress upgrade from 4.7.1 to 4.7.2, I could not add tinymce buttons anymore.

I checked that javascript was definitely running. and it was working fine with wp 4.7.1

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution that worked in my case 
run phpmyadmin (or any other database managment solution)
in table wp_options find can_compress_scripts and change value to 0

Comment: Sorry for the late. i went away for 2 weeks.
Thanks for the solution.
I never thought JS compression would cause the problem....

Comment: Hmm same problem here, but that didn't fix it for me. I can see that the JS is being called but it never gets past the `tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'add_dropcap_class', function( editor, url ) {` line.